# Can anyone help to Fetch the data from this api in flutter

Tags: flutter, api

https://www.dubaisuperstore.com.pk//myapi//product

Model which i make in flutter

```
class ProductModel {
  String? count;
  List<ProductDetail>? productDetail;

  ProductModel({this.count, this.productDetail});
}

class ProductDetail {
  int? RowId;
  int? SKUId;
  String? SKUName;
  int? SKUCatId;
  String? Category;
  int? SKUSubCatId;
  String? Sub_Category;
  String? SKURemarks;
  String? SKUActive;
  int? SalePrice;
  int? RetailPrice;
  int? SKUDiscPerc;
  String? SKUImageURL1;

  ProductDetail(
      {this.RowId,
      this.SKUId,
      this.SKUName,
      this.SKUCatId,
      this.Category,
      this.SKUSubCatId,
      this.Sub_Category,
      this.SKURemarks,
      this.SKUActive,
      this.SalePrice,
      this.RetailPrice,
      this.SKUDiscPerc,
      this.SKUImageURL1});
}
```

this is the link of api which i want to fetch ihave checked this api is in both format xml and json try to help me

Comment: what format is the response?

Comment: the format of api is json and xml both i am not getting any data through this api it seems that fetching is not proper or anyother issue

Comment: check the response of API and then try to pass it in the model class.

Comment: That looks like XML to me, so use the `xml` package to parse it. https://pub.dev/packages/xml Or ask the server maintainer if there's a way to request the data in a different format (e.g. JSON)

Comment: the response of this api is in json but when we open it in chrome it shows in xml i am trying but not getting data while considering it as json

Comment: Well, that's strange... No idea why Chrome displays it as XML. When I look in Postman it looks just like JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should get you started:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('https://www.dubaisuperstore.com.pk/myapi/product'),
  );
  final topList = json.decode(response.body) as List;
  final topObject = topList[0] as Map<String, dynamic>;
  print('There are ${topObject['Count']} products! That is a lot!');

  final productList = topObject['productDetail'] as List;
  final secondProduct = productList[1] as Map<String, dynamic>;
  print('The second product is ${secondProduct['SKUName']}. Sounds tasty');

  // at this point you could: productList.map(xxx) to turn all the product JSON objects to your model objects
}
```

This prints:

```
There are 5522 products! That is a lot!
The second product is 3 HORSES MALT DRINK 330ML. Sounds tasty
```

Comment: If that helped, it's traditional to *accept* the answer. (And then to create new questions for any follow up issues.)